# SQL join: how to select when value not in a set of values

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, table1 and table2. Table1 is in a one to many relationship with table2 (one row in table1 maps to many rows in table2). There is a field in table2 called code. If none of the values of code in table2 equal some set of values (say 1, 2, and 3), I want to select the value in table1.  I'm not sure how to write this kind of join.
Assume the primary key in table1 is called id and the foreign key to which it maps is called did. Can you tell me how to write this kind of join?

Comment: Can you please provide a break down of the table structure?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN` , `NOT IN`, or `EXCEPT` what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

The easiest implementation is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2
                  WHERE  table2.did = table1.id
                    AND  table2.code in (1,2,3))
```

or, using outer join (I'm not 100% sure this will work, as I always use NOT EXIST syntax myself for antijoins):

```
SELECT  table1.*
FROM    table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table2
ON      table1.id = table2.did
  AND  table2.code in (1,2,3)
WHERE   table2.did is NULL
```

Comment: Check your database but not exists tends to be faster than the left join for this purpose.

Comment: @HLGEM - there's a pretty good page explaining the performance implications of various antijoins for MySQL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: And for SQL server http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.did
```

Comment: Possible, the requirement is not much clear in question itself, thats why I kept it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be asked more clearly.  Need to attend to your natural language as well as to your SQL.  I may not have understood your question. Note sure what you mean by "If none of the values of code in table2 equal some set of values (say 1, 2, and 3), I want to select the *value* in table1.". Do you mean "the *row* in table 1"? And instead of "equals some set" do you mean "is found in some set"?

If you have two tables in a one to many relationship, e.g. Composers and Works:

```
               COMPOSERS
               composerid
               composername
               DOB

              WORKS
              workid
              workname
              composerid
              datecomposed
              worktype  (e.g. sonata, string quartet, quintet, symphony)
```

and you want to find all of a composer's works that are not sonatas or quintets, you'd do this:

```
            select composer.composername, works.workname, worktype
            from COMPOSERS inner join WORKS
            on COMPOSERS.composerid = WORKS.composerid
            WHERE worktype not IN ('sonata','quintet')
```

IF worktype allowed nulls, you'd have to add  " or worktype is null" to the where-clause if you wanted works without a worktype entered into the record.

Comment: The OP wants to find all composers that have never written a sonata or quintet