# How to do a left join on a run-time generated tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, not-exists, notin

I have two tables in the database (myCustomTable1 and myCustomTable2) and from them I'm creating another two tables (Table1 and Table2) which are created during the run time. **Now I need to take the rows which are inside of Table1, but are not in the Table2.**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571871/sql-join-how-to-select-when-value-not-in-a-set-of-values), which seems that contains the answer that I need, but I'm not able to implement this with my solution, because as said, tables which I need to "antijoin" are generated during run-time.

Both of my (run-time generated) tables have the format:

```
-----------------------
|  Column1 | Column2  |
-----------------------
|          |          |
-----------------------
|          |          |
-----------------------
```

Here is the code that I have.

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM (
    SELECT  myCustomTable1.Column1,
            myCustomTable1.Column2
    ) as Table1 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Table2.* FROM (
        SELECT  myCustomTable2.Column1,
                myCustomTable2.Column2
    ) as Table2 
)
ON  Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
AND Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2
```

Now I'm aware that this solution is not working, because when trying to join, I'm trying to use Table2, which is not available in the global scope, but I can not find any appropriate solution.

Maybe using `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `NOT IN` is also an option, but in every try, I faced with the same issue where the scope of the defined tables is a problem.

Comment: Why don't you show us how do you create them during runtime? A table variable, a temp table, a CTE are all created at runtime and yet they are all in the scope.

Comment: Since you are only interested in records from table 1, `NOT EXISTS` would probably be a better way.

Comment: If scope is the issue you need to give an example of the code that creates the tables and then tries to reference them.  You're saying that the `LEFT JOIN` isn't the issue, but how SQL-Sever manages scope is the issue; so show us what you're trying to do.  *(It's likely that you're creating table variables, but that using temporary tables would be better suited, to be sure we need to see your code...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a lot easier to separate your sets in CTEs:

```
;WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT  
        myCustomTable1.Column1,
        myCustomTable1.Column2
    FROM
        myCustomTable1
),
Table2 AS
(
    SELECT  
        myCustomTable2.Column1,
        myCustomTable2.Column2
    FROM
        myCustomTable2
)
SELECT *
FROM Table1 as t1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Table2 as t2
            WHERE t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 
              AND t1.Column2 = t2.Column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed  a from table in the inner suquery and a  table alias  in the outer left join try use

```
  SELECT Table1.* FROM (
      SELECT  myCustomTable1.Column1,
              myCustomTable1.Column2
      ) as Table1 
  LEFT JOIN
  (
      SELECT Table2.* FROM (
          SELECT  myCustomTable2.Column1,
                  myCustomTable2.Column2
          FROM myCustomTable2
      ) as Table2 
  ) as  table 3 
  ON  Table1.Column1 = Table3.Column1
  AND Table1.Column2 = Table3.Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `select` the records from `Table1` excluding the matches using `not exists` in the `where`:

```
select *
from Table1
where
not exists(select 1
           from Table2
           where Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1 and Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the aliases Table1 and Table2 as runtime created wouldn't this work?:

```
SELECT Table1.* 
FROM (
    SELECT  myCustomTable1.Column1,
            myCustomTable1.Column2
    ) as Table1 
LEFT JOIN
(
        SELECT  myCustomTable2.Column1,
                myCustomTable2.Column2
) as Table2
ON  Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
AND Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2
where Table2.Column1 is null;
```

Or (better IMHO):

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2
from  myCustomTable1 t1
where not exists 
(
        SELECT * from myCustomTable2 t2 where 
t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 and t1.Column2 = t2.Column2
);
```